# come back to the same jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a page named requisition.jsp on which first submit the form to raise requisition in which i mention number of visitors. It goes to servlet and come back to requisition.jsp with following way:

```
String id = Integer.toString(req_id);
request.setAttribute("id", id);
request.getRequestDispatcher("requisition.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Now on my requisition.jsp page I have the form which I already submitted and below it are the number of tabs equal to the number of visitors i entered. In each tab there is one form for visitor. I do fill form for first visitor and submit it. It goes to the servlet to add visitor and from there comes to requisition.jsp by:

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("requisition.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But here i should be coming to the requisition.jsp page where i had submit the form for first visitor but i m yet to submit the forms for other visitors. Instead i am coming to the whole new requisition.jsp page. Whole new means there are no tabs i.e. no form for visitor.

I need to use only servlet and jsp or javascript. Please help this is my first encounter with web application development.

Comment: If you want to submit a form without losing current stuff on page, use Ajax rather than normal HTML form submit. Because obviously if you submit, forward over here, forward over there, finally forward back, some stuff on the original page is probably gone now.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution but not the proper one. Just posting it here. I succumbed to situation and created an intermediate jsp as below for now:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Visitor Management System</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.history.back();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It worked for now.